# Is there any way I can ride blocks like they were horses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I just made a resource pack with a 3D model of the "Swegway/IOHawk/PhunkeeDuck/Hoverboard"-thing. The texture I changed is the flower pot. Now im just wondering if I can somehow ride blocks (like the flower pot) like it is a horse or minecart?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sort of.
If you summon an invisible minecart/horse to the same block, the player can still right click to ride it. You can't move around like this, though. In order to do that you would need some command logic, and because of the grid system blocks work on, it wouldn't look very smooth.